# Deleting old no-answer questions?

Tags: discussion, support

I deleted some questions of mine that had no answers. Is this acceptable to do?

I know they show up in deleted when logged in, but that's not breaking rules, is it?

Comment: Where the questions closed and/or down voted?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: You should know. It is important

Comment: Also: why do you cross-post the same question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361471/deleting-old-no-answer-questions ?

Comment: No votes; just checked.

Comment: Okay, if your questions are not answered, not closed and don't have downvotes then deleting might not have consequences. Keep in mind that deleted questions can never earn an upvote so if you run into a quality ban for the remaining questions you might have wished you kept those deleted questions around and up to date.

Comment: I'm missing context here. Why did you choose to delete it? Was it a bad question you asked a long time ago or did you figure out the answer to it yourself meanwhile perhaps?

Comment: If you aren't removing something of value (which the system would generally prevent anyway) there's no overall harm. just don't dig yourself into a hole with the question ban system